# acumatica: Fixed Asset entry

Tags: fixed, acumatica

In acumatica ERP, I'm trying to place fixed asset items that are already recorded in the trial balance.  (So I basically just want to add them to the fixed asset subledger)

How should I use the 'update GL' option button in the preferences; given that I don't want a new asset to increase the fixed asset GL account?

I'm a good enough accountant to correct the trial balance even if an item is 'posted to GL' when I don't want it to.  But as I try and 'release' an addition: i'm getting this error:

"Error: An error occurred while processing the field Account value 9714 Error: 'Account' 9714 cannot be found in the system. Please verify if you have proper access rights to this object.."

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks
Brandon

Alex Turok, Thanks for answering my previous question.

Comment: Please note that this site is meant for programming questions; your question will most liekly be closed by moderators.

Comment: I understand Gabriel; I do want to do extensive programming, here related to fixed assets.  But I'm first restricted by the fact that I can't manually interact with this ERP system, Acumatica.

Answer (score 2):

There are quick steps for initial import fixed assets:

1. import trial balance (done)
2. setup FA module
3. uncheck 'Update GL' in FA Preferences
4. import fixed assets.
5. release FA transactions, if you have 'Automatically Release Acquisition Transactions' - *false* in FA Preferences
6. After initialization is done set 'Update GL' - *true*.

Unlike transactions in other financial modules, you can have fixed asset transactions that are not linked to general ledger transactions. If you select the 'Update GL' check box, the system starts generating GL transactions when you release fixed asset transactions. If the Update GL check box is cleared, the system doesn't generate journal transactions when you release fixed asset transactions. While you are preparing the system for production use, you can clear the check box during initial data migration to import the fixed assets
that are already capitalized without affecting GL balances.

Regarding error during release, please check if account is active.

Regards,
Evgeny Pogorely

Comment: Thanks for for your help; I hit the 'Automatically Release Acquisition Transactions' which might have helped the update.    One last question; I need to add previous Accumulated Depreciation to assets.  I saw how to use 'calculate' depreciation; but the system won't allow me to 'depreciate' without turning on 'update GL'.  I want to force prior depreciation (without recording it); or add 'accumlated depreciation'' without 'updating GL'.  Any suggestions?  thanks again.  Brandon